# Which cursor is Appropriate for kids math educational application?

Tags: math, typing

There are some boxes on my app screens where users (kids) should type numbers in them by keyboard. Which cursor along with transition effect should we use to kids understand that they should type in it?

Comment: are these simple text input fields, where they can also insert the cursor to copy or paste values as well?

Comment: @MikeM The input boxes just for typing a number, they has not copy and paste option

Comment: Is there any reason you can't just use the traditional text cursor? If the interface sticks with common input conventions, users (of all ages) will be more likely to know how to interact with your system.

Comment: exactly. I don't see any other reason for another cursor.

Answer (score 3):

I don't have enough reputation points to add a comment, I apologize. However, I agree, altering a standard can be really confusing. If kids need to fill in answers, why not highlight the textbox?

Comment: this shouldn't be a comment. While not answering the question directly, with a bit of explanation this is a good answer and great solution for the OP problem

Answer (score 2):

#### If you have a standard input, stick to a familiar cursor.

Even though they are not copying or pasting text as you indicated above, they are still placing the cursor in the text field (to prepare to enter a number) as a mouse option (correct me if I'm wrong)

Here's the **[MDN (Mozilla Developer Network) list of cursors](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/cursor):**

[image]

**UPDATE**

The cursor change is helpful for when the mouse is entering the input area, but as user @ciammarino indicated below, without any mouse movements, is it clear to the user what is required for input?

We don't have a screenshot of your app, so it's hard to give specifics, but this is a consideration as well...